# ios UINavgationController setNavigationBarHidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a navgationController and its rootViewContoller is tabViewController. The tableviewController contains five viewControllers, currently, I hided the navgationBar successfully by adding `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]` in `viewWillAppear`, and adding `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated]` in `viewWillDisappear`

But when I push a newController which contains a tableview, the tableview cannot scroll to the bottom and pop from the newController to the homepage, there is a black blank height for 64 on the tabbar, the tableview frame has changed! what I should do! Help!

Comment: I just want to hide the navgationBar in homepage controller

Comment: try this "[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];"

Comment: i have a try,doesnot work!

Answer (score 0):

if write code for your purpose，I will set a tabBarController as window.rootViewController.
The tabBarController can contains five navigationController subclass of  [JTNavigationController](https://github.com/JNTian/JTNavigationController),  JTNavigationController's viewcontroller can custom navigationBar Independent。

Comment: i agree with you , i designed my another project as you said,

Answer (score 0):

just add this in the viewWillAppear of controller where you want to hide the navigationbar
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
and to unhide it add this in viewWillAppear of the particular controller
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;